# how to parse first and second occurrence of number between two strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring, instr

can you help me with parse of numbers from string?

I want select first and second occurrence of number from string that look like :

```
 PKGGeneral.SetObjectAttribute(i_DimObject=4,i_ObjectID=163225122,i_Attribute=NAME,i_Value (VarChar2)=xDSL:1.4.51);
```

or

```
PKGPort.CreateLogicalPort(io_portid=197604073,i_name=VLAN_segment:7239554:IPTV GPON_Port_A,i_nodeid=123431890,i_porttypeid=1900000150,i_bandwidthid=1,i_parentportid=186300246);
```

First occurrence set into column A and second  occurrence set into column B.

Result:
**example A**

```
column A : 4
column B : 163225122
```

**example B**

```
column A : 197604073
column B : 7239554
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide what you have you tried so far and what the problem is you're facing with that.

Answer (score -1):

Use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select
    regexp_substr(mycol, '\d+', 1, 1) colA,
    regexp_substr(mycol, '\d+', 1, 2) colB
from mytable
```

`\d+` captures a continuous series of digits. The fourth argument indicates which occurence should be returned.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7815d8e973a09d4d2bf51985ec406e30)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'PKGGeneral.SetObjectAttribute(i_DimObject=4,i_ObjectID=163225122,i_Attribute=NAME,i_Value (VarChar2)=xDSL:1.4.51);' mycol from dual
    union all
    select 'PKGPort.CreateLogicalPort(io_portid=197604073,i_name=VLAN_segment:7239554:IPTV GPON_Port_A,i_nodeid=123431890,i_porttypeid=1900000150,i_bandwidthid=1,i_parentportid=186300246);' from dual
)
select
    regexp_substr(mycol, '\d+', 1, 1) colA,
    regexp_substr(mycol, '\d+', 1, 2) colB
from mytable
```

```
COLA      | COLB     
:-------- | :--------
4         | 163225122
197604073 | 7239554
```